# Comparisson between different intesities of Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics

I've couldn't find this information anywhere else. How strong is a 300 N/C electric field? Can you give me some examples of strong and weaker electric field applications?

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: What do you mean by "how strong"? In what context? You need to define what you mean by strength. If you mean magnitude then the answer is 300 N/C, and a stronger/weaker field will have a magnitude of more/less than 300 N/C.

Comment: I mean in comparison to something like a cathode-ray tube. At what intensity of electric field does something like that operate? And what are some other real-world applications of electric fields of varying intensities

Comment: Also, what I mean by strength: how much an electron moving through that field is deviated from its original travelling path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the electric field strength between two flat parallel plates (of length and breadth or diameter much greater than their separation) is given by$$E=\frac{V}{d}$$ in which $V$ is the plate separation and $V$ is the pd between the plates.

You could therefore create your field of 300 $\text{N}\ \text{C}^{-1}$ by placing a pd of 30 V between plates 10 cm apart. I'd call this a lowish field.

An electric field strength of about $3 \times 10^6\ \text{N}\ \text{C}^{-1}$ is enough to cause air at ordinary pressures to break down and conduct. Field strengths of a little less than this are produced by the 'corona wire' in a photocopier, in order to 'spray' charge on to the photosensitive cylinder.